# What sound frequencies does a circular saw emit?

Tags: noise, noise-reduction, saw

I'm trying to find the best way to sound proof my garage so that using a circular saw would go un-noticed by the neighbors. ( Our strata have rules for noise regulation )

But before ordering anything, I have to figure out what kind of sounds frequencies I'm fighting with. The circular saw is pretty much the most loud tool I can think of when it come to wood works in a garage.

What sound frequencies is a circular saw blade produce when cutting wood ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole paper dedicated to your problem... [a study of a table saw's noisiness](http://www.me.mtu.edu/courses/meem4704/project/papers/nc03_table_saw.pdf)

Comment: Answers consisting only of links, are only helpful as long as the link is active.  Consider summarizing some of the information in the link here, so if the link dies this answer may still be useful.

Comment: The paper says that foam will help for 1-10Hz frequencies, but doesn't explain what frequencies a table saw makes. ( As blocking 1-10Hz only reduce the noise by 6DBa )

Comment: @DMoore: The link is broken. Perhaps this link is similar? http://www.sawmillcreek.org/showthread.php?144824-Table-saw-noise-study&s=a6f7317095acda2c977ab0b57c855498

Answer (score 0):

Circular saws and the most inexpensive tablesaws use universal motors which are extremely noisy.  It will be very difficult to soundproof a typical garage so that one of these tools will go unnoticed.  The main garage door will be a particular problem because of it's thinness and the gaps at the edges.

Induction motors are far quieter than universal motors, so I suggest that an investment in a table saw with an induction motor may be a better way to spend what you have budgeted for soundproofing.  Your ears will thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the tip... but I'll need to sound proof even with an induction table saw... So I guess my question still apply :)